# Grep CPU and other hardware percentage using top command?

Tags: bash, grep, ash

I need to measure my CPU percentage usage and memory.
Using top command will give this result (see the red sign)
[image: cpu info 1]

Another command by typing

```
top -d 1 | grep -w "CPU"
```

The result is like this.
[image: CPU INFO 2]

How do i grab the percent value of cpu usage to a variable in bash linux?
Need help everyone :) 
Many thanks

Comment: Why would you use `top` from that rather than just pulling the data directly from procfs? I mean, `top` doesn't make guarantees that its output can be parsed at all, and can break its formatting at will in any future version, whereas the kernel's procfs interface actually makes documented, forward-compatible promises about content. (And it's where `top` gets its data from; why not go there directly yourself?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the `CPU` percentage value you can use `top -n1 -b` command and pipe it to `awk`:

```
top -n 1 -b | awk '/^%Cpu/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `mpstat` rather than `top` is much easier to parse information regarding processor.

```
mpstat -P ALL 1 1

-P to indicate processor `ALL` for all of them
and shows 1 interval of 1 second
```